# Move an absolute positioned element's right side to the left side of it's parent

Tags: html, css

**The Problem**

I have a container within another one. The rule `display: inline-block;` on the outer container is a given. I want that the content of the inner container *ends* where the content of the outer one starts. I tried using `left: -100%;` but naturally it moves the content only as far as the outer container is wide. The use case: The inner element will be a tooltip shown on hover aligned on the left side.

How can I got both elements aligned after each other and not overlapping without using JavaScript?

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Short content
    <div>This is very long test sentence.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px 200px;
    background: rgba(123, 234, 345, 0.7);
}

div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: -100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Demo on jsFiddle**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dkv9W/)

Comment: Don't add tooltips like that.. create them dynamically. I'm sure there is lot of plugins for this.. for example: http://qtip2.com/

Comment: @Hardy Why not? The content is available for screenreaders, the element is self contained and I can create the whole tooltip without JavaScript.

Comment: And if i have to put tooltips like that for 100 elements in 100 pages..? Not that sensible way to go..

Comment: @Hardy I really don't get your last comment. Can you explain it a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing sense to create own elements for every single tooltip (up front).. you should use `title` tag and some plugin.. if you can't get it not my fault..

Comment: @Hardy OK, now I get what you want. In most cases this might be a good approach, depending on the content presented. And yes, the *reduced* example in my question might lead to that conclusion. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `right: 100%;` instead of `left: -100%;`. Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/dkv9W/1/

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. I only tried `right` with `-100%` as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Hardy, no, it is not :)

Comment: why so? can you explain.. it is just confusing..  if `right: 0px;` put element to absolute right side isn't `right:100%` should put element to absolute left?

Comment: @Hardy, here is a quick explanation from here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) `it specifies the distance between the left margin edge of the element and the left edge of its containing block.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put the objects in line just remove the `left: -100%`.

http://jsfiddle.net/dkv9W/3/